# UWP C# Puzzling behaviour on String (Array) Join & Split operations with Carriage Return CR ("\r") and Line Feed LF ("\n") as separators

Tags: c#, uwp, compiler-construction

I have come across a curious thing in my UWP C# App (Runtime Component), 
Assume variable "dbLines" is a List with 300 items in it, if I do:

```
(String.Join("\r", dbLines)).Split("\r")
```

You expect to get 300 strings out of Split, right?

but I only get one big string out of Split!

Split simply doesn't work because it fails to find any carriage return ("\r") in there??

But if I use New Line (Line Feed):

```
(String.Join("\n", dbLines)).Split("\n")
```

I all works as expected!

This also works fine too:

```
(String.Join("\r", dbLines)).Replace("\r","\n").Split("\n")
```

Can anyone explain why?? Is it a compiler thing or something else?

Comment: Are you sure `\r` exists in the string? If the file is sourced from linux, `\n` could very well be the only separator.

Comment: Best to check using `Environment.NewLine` as this would handle Windows `"\r\n"` and non-Windows `"\n"` cases.